# Immaculate Reception Legality

Tags: rules, officiating, nfl

Was the touchdown at the end of the game between the Steelers and the Raiders in the [1972 AFC Divisional playoff game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immaculate_Reception) legally a touchdown by the NFL double touch rules or was the pass first touched by the Steelers' receiver?

Comment: Well, the Steelers won, so yes in practice.  I've never seen a replay that was convincing one way or the other.  One of those deep mysteries of sports...

Comment: NO! I say no! It was, and still is, and always will be raiders against the world.

Comment: @skullpatrol like how the "tuck rule" wasn't a fumble?

Comment: @edmastermind29 the steelers, like the patriots were the darlings of their respective decades.

Answer (score 4):

Oh I know this one!  My first cousin, Fred Swearingen #21 was the referee.  The best answer is by the off-field official, Art McNally IN USA TODAY below.  It wasn't my cousin's best call.  But it was LEGAL!  Fred had called a conference to debate the "double-touch" rule. Steelers' QB Bradshaw threw a pass which caromed off Pittsburgh running back Frenchie Fuqua, then hit Oakland Raiders' defensive back Jack Tatum, then scooped up by Pittsburgh's Franco Harris.  LEGAL TOUCHDOWN!

http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nfl/2012/12/18/art-mcnally-recalls-immaculate-reception-40-years-later-denies-looking-at-the-replay/1778279/

Fred had ANOTHER controversial call also involving the Steelers and Lynn Swann in Super Bowl XIII.

Answer (score 2):

The call on the field was that the ball rebounded from the Oakland defender, and was caught before it hit the ground by Franco Harris, making it a legal reception and a touchdown.

Those facts, and whether the entire city of Pittsburgh ought to be burned to the ground have been debated by Raiders fans ever since.